# How should i validate the date format for this UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns6nC.png) there is a popup in which there are some digits.  The first 8 digits are in YYYYMMDD format. I have to validate that if the date entered is a past (earlier) date, then a message should show in the popup below the text field saying 'past date'.   If the date is the current day or a future day, then it should move to the next viewController.

Comment: Don't force your users to enter date strings in a particular format. Have separate text fields, or use a picker view.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *strTextField = @"20151012122";
NSString *strDate = [strTextField substringToIndex:8];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *pDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];

NSDate *pCurrentDate = [NSDate date];

if ([pDate compare:pCurrentDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"past date, pDate is less than current date.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"should move to the next viewController");
}
```

Comment: Date formatter should be `yyyyMMdd`. Capitalisation does matter. Specially in `day` component. For more details refer to http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/